# Workflow "Wait for field change" not waiting when a field is empty

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a problem with my workflow where the "Wait for field change" isn't waiting when a field is empty. It goes on to create a task even though the field hasn't got a date set.  The problem with this is that the task is dependent on the date in the empty field.

My workflow works like this:

**Set 'Confirmation Date' to 'Target Date:20 days'** 
(this sets 'Confirmation Date' to 'Target Date:plus 20 days')

**then Wait for Confirmation date' to be greater than 01/01/1900 00:00:00**
(this should wait until the 'Confirmation date' is not null)

**then Start 'Deal with Complaint' process on 'Current item with 'Current item:Officer'**
(this should only be created once there's a date in the 'Confirmation date' field)

**then set 'Date dealt with complaint' to 'today'**

I need the workflow to wait for the 'Confirmation date' to be set before going on to creating a task. What's happening is that the task is created even when a 'Confirmation Date' hasn't been set, causing the workflow to throw an error as the task's 'Due date' is the 'Confirmation Date'.

Any ideas why?

*(Sorry for the confusion! What I forgot to mention was, that on occasions (which we don't yet know why), the 'Confirmation date' isn't being set correctly. The 'Wait for Confirmation date ...' is suppose to be a short term work-around, until we find out why the 'Confirmation Date' is being left empty.)

Comment: I don't understand. In the first step you set the confirmation date to be TargetDate + 20. So the confirmation date is now no longer null, but it has a date. So of course there is no wait. There is a flaw either in your logic or in your description of the workflow steps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! What I forgot to mention was that on occasions (which we don't yet know why), the 'Confirmation date' isn't being set correctly. The 'Wait for Confirmation date ...' is suppose to be a short term work- around, until we find out why the 'Confirmation Date' isn't being set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a condition that checks if confirmation date is greater than 01/01/1900 00:00:00 and do the Wait only if it is not.

Comment: I've given this a go on the test site, it seems to have worked. I'll have to see whether it will on the live site when the issue arises. Will report back if it's successful. Thanks teylyn.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the confirmation date value in some variable and use for statement then Wait for Confirmation date' to be greater than so that you don't have nay null value.